# Proper use of Unity 4.6 MoveTowards

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine

I have been working on this for several days without success. I made a sprite animation of a bird flapping it's wings. I want to make the bird fly to a specific spot in a tree. The tree is an image, which has a child image with the animation attached. The animation works fine, but I want to move it to a branch on the tree. The class listed below is attached to the child image, but the bird doesn't move toward the branch.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class FlyBird : MonoBehaviour {

    public Transform target; // Target is empty game object defined in the inspector
    public float MoveSpeed; // Set to 10 in the inspector

    // Script is attached to an Image object and the child of the image is a sprite animation

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.position, MoveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        Debug.Log(transform.position.x);
    }
}
```

Comment: hmm... not sure what you're behavior you're expecting just tested this script and it works just fine, what's happening to you?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your current behaviour is, but a possibility is that you're moving on FixedUpdate(), so you should use Time.fixedDeltaTime instead of Time.deltaTime

Comment: I changed it to Time.fixedDeltaTime and there was no difference.

Comment: I see. I'll make another answer. I believe it's because you're using an Image object.

Answer (score 0):

You're using an UI Image, if I got correctly after your edit.
For this type of object, you should use its RectTransform instead of Transform.
Try this:

```
rectTransform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(rectTransform.position, target.rectTransform.position, MoveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
```

Supposing you can get rectTransform from target object, of course. Another way could be to manipulate rectTransform.anchoredPosition.

Check more information about this type of Rect Transform here: http://docs.unity3d.com/460/Documentation/ScriptReference/RectTransform.html

Comment: The second argument in Vector2.MoveTowards target.RectTransform.position creates an error. I even tried making the target another image. Then I tried making it an empty game object and using target.transform.position for the second argument and still generates an error.

Comment: @jadkins4 is the target also an UI component or a regular object with a normal transform instead of RectTransform?

Comment: The target is an empty game object. I used target.transform.position as the second argument. That didn't work. I also tried a UI Image as the target and used target.RectTransform.position and that didn't work either. Is there a better way to make an animated sprite move to a position?